# How to center a heading / title with bootstrap (or using CSS, but in a bootstrap website)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've set the background of the below section (just 1 container-fluid) to be the gradient image you can see, and I'd like 2 things to happen here:

1. I'd like the background image to fill up the entire screen, regardless of screen size (I've used background-size: cover, but there is still all the whitespace)
2. I'd like the text headers to be centered in the middle of said page (or maybe slightly up from center), again regardless of screen size - I understand on mobile it will be more cramped and that's fine.

How would I do this, and does bootstrap have classes / functionality to do this? Or will I just be using CSS and doing things like margin auto / pushing it down the page with em / px, etc?

[image]

Only CSS outside of vanilla Bootstrap is here:

```
.navbar {
background: none;
border: none;
}

#frontpage {
background-image: url("../images/titlebg.jpg");
background-size: cover; 
}
```

Frontpage is just the title of the main first section that I'm referring to with the question. 
Thank you!

Comment: Try background-size: 100% and bootstrap has a .text-center class you can play around with. Put up a fiddle for a better answer

Comment: Please post a complete, working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS). [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can see the bootstrap examples [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples), Pick one you like open it up and look at the source code. All the styles and classes you need are there in the examples. Its how I got started and the best way to learn.